# How to find area of covered pixel in video after adding points to the video sequence?

Tags: python, video, computer-vision

I have a video of crowded scenes and its masked image of black and white pixels. At first, here is the frame from video sequence.

[image]

Above image's ground truth masked image is following.

[image]

At first, the number of white pixels are count (only bike is shown as white pixels):

```
    ret_gt,frame_gt=cap_pixel_level_gt.read()
    cp_frame_gt = deepcopy((frame_gt[:, :, 0] > 200).astype(int))

    numberOfPixelsBefore=np.count_nonzero(cp_frame_gt)
```

This gives number of white pixels in every frame.Example:

```
0
0
0
0  
496
496
606
609
609
```

For a total length of 180 frames, it gives number of white pixels. After applying algorithm, the bike in original video are marked with red points. Here is the frame with output trajectories. Now I need to find number of red pixels in every image frame of video sequences. For this I do as:

```
 cv2.circle(frame_gt,(int(TrajData[ind][0][1]), int(TrajData[ind][0][2])), 4, (0, 0, 0), -1)
 cp_frame_gt = deepcopy((frame_gt[:, :, 0] > 200).astype(int))
```

frame_gt is groundtruth video (masked  ) and TrajData gives coordinates of points for which pixels is to be made red.

After adding trajectories point to ground truth video, I need to find number of pixels with non zero.

```
numberOfPixelsAfter=np.count_nonzero(cp_frame_gt)
```

But every time it is showing same number of pixels in ground truth video and next groundtruthvideo where we add pixels as black pixels.

How to find number of pixels that is overlapped with ground truth video by trajectories coordinate?

[image]